# Base64 files corrupt upon upload via SP rest in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate

I am trying to use a SharePoint request action in Power Automate to upload a file to a library.  I'm running into an issue that I've seen many others who have attempted this either using the SP JSOM or jquery/ajax calls in that any file other than a 'txt' is corrupt when uploaded.

Does anyone know how to properly use PowerAutomate to upload a file to SP with REST?

I am converting the my base64 string into binary via the base64tobinary() expression. Uri endpoints and headers are as follows:

```
    method: post
    uri: _api/web/lists/getbytitle('shareddocs')/RootFolder/files/add(overwrite=true,url='filename')
    headers:  {
    accept:  application/json; odata=verbose,
    content-type:  application/octet-stream
    }
    body:  base64tobinary('base64var')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be the direct answer to your question, but it is probably easier to use the native "Create file" action instead of the REST:

[image]

Comment: Yes, if I could use the native I definitely would however I need my solution to be dynamic.

Comment: Create file is quite dynamic. every field here can be a variable

Comment: whoops sorry. i misread your reply.  i’ll see if i can go this route. thanks!